# how to sort hash in descending order with out changing position of same value ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

```
hash = {"p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p3"=>0, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56, "p6"=>64, "p7"=>0}

p Hash[hash.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse] # gives 
{"p6"=>64, "p5"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p1"=>56, "p3"=>0}
```

But I want output something like below

```
{"p6"=>64, "p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56}
```

Also , final hash don't require key with zero.

Comment: Don't bother sorting hashes, there's no advantage to it. Instead, retrieve the keys and sort those to supply an order for retrieving the values, or convert the hash to an array and sort that. Really, it's not worth the CPU time to sort the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p Hash[
  hash.reject { |_, v| v.zero? }.sort do |kv1, kv2| 
    (val = kv1.last <=> kv2.last).zero? ? kv2.first <=> kv1.first : val
  end.reverse]

#⇒ {"p6"=>64, "p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56}
```

**UPD** With block variables expressed as suggested by @CarySwoveland and removing superfluous `reverse`:

```
p Hash[
  hash.reject { |_, v| v.zero? }.sort do |(k1,v1), (k2,v2)| 
    (val = v2 <=> v1).zero? ? k1 <=> k2 : val
  end
]

#⇒ {"p6"=>64, "p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56}
```

**NB**: the above will sort keys for same values, while @Cary’s answer below won’t.

Comment: Nice solution. Consider expressing the block variables `|(k1,v1),(k2,v2)|`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. I personally don’t like block vars expressing, don’t ask me why :) BTW, swapping `kvN` conditions helps to get rid of latter `reverse` call.

Comment: Why? :-). Hari, with the block variables "disambiguated" as I suggested,, the operative line reads: ` (v1==v2) ? k2.<=> k1 : v1`. (I also simplified slightly.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
hash.reject { |_,v| v.zero? }
    .each_with_index
    .sort_by { |(_,v),i| [-v,i] }
    .map(&:first)
    .to_h
  #=> {"p6"=>64, "p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56}
```

For Ruby versions prior to 2.0, replace `arr.to_h` with `Hash[arr]`.

The steps:

```
h = hash.reject { |_,v| v.zero? }
  #=> {"p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56, "p6"=>64} 
e = h.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56,
  #                  "p6"=>64}:each_with_index> 
a = e.sort_by { |(_,v),i| [-v,i] }
  #=> [[["p6", 64], 4], [["p1", 56], 0], [["p2", 56], 1],
  #    [["p4", 56], 2], [["p5", 56], 3]]
b = a.map(&:first)
  #=> [["p6", 64], ["p1", 56], ["p2", 56], ["p4", 56], ["p5", 56]]
b.to_h
  #=> {"p6"=>64, "p1"=>56, "p2"=>56, "p4"=>56, "p5"=>56}
```

We can see the values of the enumerator `e` that will be passed into the block by converting it to an array:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[["p1", 56], 0], [["p2", 56], 1], [["p4", 56], 2],
  #    [["p5", 56], 3], [["p6", 64], 4]]
```

**Edit**: if I misunderstood the question (see comments below), and @mudasobwa's interpretation is correct, my solution could be modified as follows:

```
hash.reject { |_,v| v.zero? }.sort_by { |k,v| [-v,k] }.to_h
```

Comment: This won’t work on shuffled input: `hash = {"p2"=>56, "p1"=>56, "p6"=>64, "p7"=>0}` (note `p2`, `p1` order.) As a matter of fact, involving index is so unfunctional :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, your example produces the result, `{"p6"=>64, "p2"=>56, "p1"=>56}`, which is consistent with my interpretation of the question: keys with equal values are to maintain their order in the hash. I noticed that you interpreted the question differently.

Comment: Aye... The more I think about the more I’m concerned _you_ interpreted the question correctly, not _me_.